# Location of JetBrains IDEs default keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

I wanted to write a tool for synchronizing keyboard shortcuts between JetBrains IDEs but I cannot find the default ones. When I customize them in the IDE, a new folder `keymaps` is created under `.tool\config` which contains only the customized assignment.

However, I need to first compare the original schemes to find differences and to merge them eventually. But I cannot find them anywhere.

I looked for various `*.xml` files with the content like `shift` or `ctrl` or `keyboard-shortcut`, no results.

Do you know where they are hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `IDE_INSTALL_FOLDER/lib/resources.jar` file (it's an ordinary ZIP archive).

All bundled keymaps will be located in `keymaps` folder inside that archive.

Comment: I got it! I didn't know `*.jar`s were like zip-archives :-o nice